# Git: List git branches, sort by (and show) date

Tags: git, list, sorting, date, branch

How can I list git branches showing and sorting by their last commits' dates?

I've found [this](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2345/show-git-branches-by-date-useful-for-showing-active-branches):

```
for k in `git branch | sed s/^..//`; do
    echo -e `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" "$k"`\\t"$k";
done | sort -r
```

I'd expect plain git to have this feature. Does it?

I also found `git show-branch --date-order` but the output is something different.

Comment: How can this be a duplicate if it's older?

Comment: How can this be older, when this was asked in 2012 and the other was asked in 2011?

Comment: All right, my bad. I was looking at the 2014 edit. Thx & appology

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This appears to be a built-in way to achieve that (v1.7.4):

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)'
```

Comment: `git for-each-ref` was added in 1.4.4.

Comment: doesn't have an analog for remote branches that I can find though

Comment: @Ry4an use `refs/remotes/` instead of `refs/heads/`

Comment: It seems that in Windows Command Prompt the `'` need to be changed to `"`.

Comment: For remote branches the same syntax works: git branch -r --sort=-committerdate --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)'

Comment: How about changing the sort from sooner to later?

Answer (score 37):

I've enjoyed the @Will Sheppard solution to put some colors.

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(color: red)%(committerdate:short) %(color: cyan)%(refname:short)'
```

Comment: @will's method works fine, but yours seems to act up on my git 183 branch (git-1.8.3.1-13.el7) .  Check it, if you could?

```fatal: unknown field name: color: red```

Comment: Works in git bash  but from within some IDE like vscode gives fatal error @user2066657

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Works on Windows if you replace `'` with `"`